# How to create an OpenGL context on an NodeJS native addon on MacOS?

Tags: c++, node.js, macos, opengl, node-native-addon

Follow-up for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022920/when-should-the-function-cglgetcurrentcontext-return-null-and-when-it-shouldnt) question.

I'm trying to create a NodeJS native addon that uses OpenGL.

I'm not able to use OpenGL functions because `CGLGetCurrentContext()` always returns `NULL`.

When trying to create a new context to draw into, `CGLChoosePixelFormat` always returns the error `kCGLBadConnection` `invalid CoreGraphics connection`.

What is bugging me out is that when I isolate the code that creates the OpenGL context into a standalone CPP project, it works! It just gives an error when I run it inside the NodeJS addon!

I created this NodeJS native addon project to exemplify my error: https://github.com/Psidium/node-opengl-context-error-example

This is the code that works when executed on a standalone project and errors out when running inside NodeJS:

```cpp
//
//  main.cpp
//  test_cli
//
//  Created by Borges, Gabriel on 4/3/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Psidium. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Context before creating it: " << CGLGetCurrentContext() << "\n";
       CGLContextObj context;
    CGLPixelFormatAttribute attributes[2] = {
            kCGLPFAAccelerated,   // no software rendering
            (CGLPixelFormatAttribute) 0
    };
    CGLPixelFormatObj pix;
    CGLError errorCode;
    GLint num; // stores the number of possible pixel formats
    errorCode = CGLChoosePixelFormat( attributes, &pix, &num );
    if (errorCode > 0) {
      std::cout << ": Error returned by choosePixelFormat: " << errorCode << "\n";
        return 10;
    }

    errorCode = CGLCreateContext( pix, NULL, &context );
    if (errorCode > 0) {
      std::cout << ": Error returned by CGLCreateContext: " << errorCode << "\n";
      return 10 ;
    }

    CGLDestroyPixelFormat( pix );

    errorCode = CGLSetCurrentContext( context );
    if (errorCode > 0) {
      std::cout << "Error returned by CGLSetCurrentContext: " << errorCode << "\n";
      return 10;
    }
    std::cout << "Context after being created is: " << CGLGetCurrentContext() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I already tried:

- Using `fork()` to create a context in a subprocess (didn't work);
- Changing the `pixelformat` attributes to something that will create my context (didn't work);

I have a hunch that it may have something to do with the fact that a Node native addon is a dynamically linked library, or maybe my OpenGL `createContext` function may not be executing on the main thread (but if this was the case, the `fork()` would have solved it, right?).

Answer (score 0):

Accessing graphics hardware requires extra permissions - Windows and macOS (don't know for others) restrict creation of hardware-accelerated OpenGL context to **interactive user session** (I may be wrong with the terms here). From one of articles on the web:

> In case the user is not logged in, the CGLChoosePixelFormat will return kCGLBadConnection

**Interactive session** is easier to *feel* than to *understand*; e.g. when you interactively login and launch application - it is interactive session; when process is started as service - it is non-interactive. How this is actually managed by system requires deeper reading. As far as I know, there is no easy way "escaping" non-interactive process flag.

NodeJS can be used as part of a web-server, so that I may expect that it can be exactly the problem - it is started as a service, by another non-interactive user or has other special conditions making it non-interactive. So maybe more details on how you use / start NodeJS itself might clarify why the code doesn't work. But I may expect that using OpenGL on server part might be not a good idea anyway (if this is a target); although it might be possible that software OpenGL implementation (without `kCGLPFAAccelerated` flag might work).

By the way, there are at least two OpenGL / WebGL extensions to NodeJS - have you tried their samples to see if they behave in the same or different way in your environment?
https://github.com/google/node-gles
https://github.com/mikeseven/node-webgl